# VS2010 cannot match PDB information

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pdb-files

I converted my vs2008 express native C++ solution to a vs2010 express solution.
It contains about 20 projects which compile well (most of the, are static libraries), but when I try to debug it, I get a meesage that the debugging information cannot be found or does not matched.
I have no no-longer-existing files in my projects and by looking at the modules tab I can see that VS loads the modules from the correct location.

What could cause this?

Comment: Have you done a __full__ clean and rebuild of the solution in VC++ 2010 after upgrading? Do you have any external dependencies (e.g. libraries) that are still built with VC++ 2008?

Comment: Are you generating PDB files for the *new* builds in VS 2010?

Comment: @ildjarn: Yes. I cleaned it completely. I even deleted the whole debug directory when it didn't help...

Answer (score 0):

This might seem like an odd solution, but have you tried restarting Visual Studio? I've experienced this as well, and occasionally, restarting seems to fix the problem: I suspect it has something to do with Visual Studio holding the PDB in memory, and a restart forces it to dump and reacquire it.

Comment: @Idov Damn, worth a try though. I'll have a look and post again if I find you another possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked, PDB settings with static libraries (that you mention) were a bit brittle - there may well be differences with how vc08 vs vc10 handle the defaults and that may not be properly converted over.

Try checking PDB settings under *compiler* (not linker) for the static libs and give them a proper output path instead of vc10.pdb